# How to count the number repeated product purchased by the same customer based on

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with

1. customer identifier (email)
2. order number (1 refers to the first order one has placed, 2 is the 2nd)
3. SKU is the product identifier.

[image]

I want to see a table that has two columns:

1. SKU
2. the number of times this product has been showed in both the 1st and 2nd order of the same customer. Or in other words, how many times the product has been ordered repeatedly.
   Something like this:

[image]

What excel function could achieve this?

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Comment: No. It cannot be achieved by PT. I am counting the number of products appear in both orders on customer level. @BigBen

Comment: Perhaps then with a helper column using `COUNTIFS`, and then a pivot table. Note that your second screenshot doesn't match the sample data in the first screenshot.

Comment: What is the countifs for? I made up the 2nd column in the 2nd screenshot. a PT can only shows how many times a SKU appears in order 1 versus order 2, but not the count of it shows in both order 1 and order 2. Hope I am explaining this correctly. @BigBen

Comment: I sure hope that's dummy data right there in the images, if not, please remove ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a helper column using `COUNTIFS`, and then a pivot table:

Helper column formula:

```
=--(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,C$2:C2,C2)>1)
```

[image]

Add a value filter to the pivot table to only show rows with a value greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a **Power Pivot** table to count distinct orders and create a measure to count repeat orders.

Here, column F is the Distinct count of customer and column G is the total count of customer for each SKU. Columns H and I are measures you can create with power pivot.

[image]